# how compare one column in different workbook using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to compare a column in different workbook. The column in workbook 1 is place in range C3 and in workbook 2 is place in range L3. The data between that are in the same arrangement. The column that I have to compare is about booking number. After compare the column, if all the data is match so the result is msgbox will pop up and said "its all match" but if not the msgbox will give information about what cell is missmatch.

**The example of the column is**

```
BOOKING NO
631609
631098
631099
629487
629488
```

for the range usually I used this type

```
(Range("C3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown))
```

Would anyone help me because I'm very beginner for using vba in excel

Comment: What if all the items match, but the order is different ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareBooking()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim diffs As String

    With Workbooks("Booking1Wb").Worksheets("booking1") '<--| change "Booking1Wb" and "booking1" to, respectively, your actual workbook and its worksheet names where to find booking numbers from C3 downwards
        Set rng1 = .Range("C3", .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp)) '<--| change "Booking2Wb" and "booking2" to, respectively, your actual workbook and its worksheet names where to find booking numbers from L3 downwards
    End With

    With Workbooks("Booking2Wb").Worksheets("booking2")
        Set rng2 = .Range("L3", .Cells(.Rows.count, "L").End(xlUp))
    End With

    For iRow = 1 To WorksheetFunction.Max(rng1.Rows.count, rng2.Rows.count)
        If rng1(iRow) <> rng2(iRow) Then diffs = diffs & iRow & vbLf
    Next

    If diffs <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Different booking numbers in rows:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & diffs
    Else
        MsgBox "All bookings match"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: May I asked u again? What is the macros to condition "when the items match, but the order is different" but I want it count as match too